# How to force chrome to download an url with custom filename

Tags: google-chrome, download, filenames

Tried this:

```
<a href="http://google.com" id="aaa" download="your-foo.txt">Download Your Foo</a>
```

Chrome unfortunatelly completely ignores the download attribute.
What can I do? Ideally to make it cross-browser...

Thanks

Comment: I want custom file extension, buddy.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested this on any other web browsers.
According to w3schools [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp), it is an HTML5 attribute and internet explorer and safari do not support it. So, if you are looking for cross-browser, this probably isn't the best solution.

Also the link you have composed is wrong, if you downloaded google.com it points to index.html(I checked) .
I tried `<a href="http://www.google.com" download>Here</a>` and opened it in the latest chrome and it downloaded index.html. So if you need google chrome compatibility do a download attribute with "[your choice].html".

If you would like cross-browser compatibility I suggest you use php to change the headers then echo google's source. If you are unfamiliar with php go to
[here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp)

Comment: I'm quite familiar with php, dont worry. Still, you didn't give me yet answer. I want something that works at least in chrome, ideally cross browser. Please paste here a JS function or anything that will be helpful.

Comment: I don't have time to check but [here](https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload) is a neat download library with error handling